# Best Visualization Platform For Sharing With External Users

Tags: visualization

I'm interested in creating some dashboards for clients. They will contain some sensitive data, so I plan on putting them behind an authentication wall (ASP.net, most likely). The dashboard will allow for filtering and sorting, but no data entry or deletion. Each dashboard will be fed by an Excel file.

My company suggested using Microsoft Power BI, but BI for web doesn't allow for private/confidential data, and any other method of sharing would require the client to have a Power BI license.

I also considered Tableau but ran into similar issues.

So broadly speaking, what's the best platform for creating web-based visualizations that can be embedded into a page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power BI gives you - Azure AD authentication , 
                   - row level security to data
So Power BI will be better option